# Issue with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I any writing a query in SQL Server to display all jobs which were received in the previous week, the query will be the basis of an automated report in Crystal Report, syntax is as below

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    DATENAME(yy, dbo.JOB.JOB_TAKEN_DATE) + '-' + DATENAME(wk, DATEADD(wk, - 1, dbo.JOB.JOB_TAKEN_DATE)) AS PERIOD,
    dbo.JOB.CUST_ORD_NO AS [ORDER NO],
    dbo.JOB.JOB_TAKEN_DATE AS RECEIVED,
    dbo.JOB.JOB_COMPLETION_DATE AS COMPLETED,
    UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.JOB.PROPERTY_LOCATION, ' ') + ' ' + dbo.JOB.PROPERTY_NAME + ' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.JOB.PROPERTY_ADDRESS, CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ') + ' ' + dbo.JOB.PROPERTY_POSTCODE) AS ADDRESS,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.JOB.WORKS_TO_BE_CARRIED_OUT, CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ') AS [WORKS ORDERED],
    dbo.JOB.JOB_TARGET_DATE,
    dbo.['TMO properties$'].F2 
FROM
    dbo.JOB 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CUSTOMERPROPERTY ON dbo.JOB.CUSTOMER_PROPERTY_ID = dbo.CUSTOMERPROPERTY.CUSTOMER_PROPERTY_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.['TMO properties$'] ON dbo.CUSTOMERPROPERTY.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE = dbo.['TMO properties$'].F1 
WHERE
    DATENAME(yy, dbo.JOB.JOB_TAKEN_DATE) + '-' + DATENAME(wk, DATEADD(wk, - 1, dbo.JOB.JOB_TAKEN_DATE)) = DATENAME(yy, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + '-' + DATENAME(wk, DATEADD(wk, - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
ORDER BY
    RECEIVED
```

When running the query I get an error

> adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please paste exact error message and some sample data for those tables involved

Comment: Why are selecting top 100%?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that you have some very early dates in your table?  If you run this SELECT DATEADD(WK, -1, '17530101'); then you get the same error, and this is because SQL Server doesn't handle dates before a cut off point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the oldest date I have in the data table is 2013.

Comment: @user3007679 What is the datatype of `job_taken_date`?

Answer (score 0):

The only place your error could be coming from in the code provided is:`dateadd(week, -1, j.job_taken_date)` which appears in both your `select` and your `where`.

You can get around this by using `datepart()` to get the `week` integer and reducing that by 1 instead of adjusting the `date` value with: `convert(varchar(2),datepart(week,j.job_taken_date)-1)`.

It looks like your `where` clause means "jobs taken this week". If that is the case, you can simplify your `where` to compare dates truncated to the week instead of the string comparison you are building now, which may be causing your error.

You can also make your query easier to read by using table aliases, and not using shorthand with date/time operations.

```
select top (100) percent 
    datename(year, j.job_taken_date) 
    + '-' 
    --+ datename(week, dateadd(week, -1, j.job_taken_date)
    + convert(varchar(2),datepart(week,j.job_taken_date)-1)
    ) as period
  , j.cust_ord_no as [order no]
  , j.job_taken_date as received
  , j.job_completion_date as completed
  , upper(isnull(j.property_location, ' ') 
    + ' ' + j.property_name + ' ' 
    + replace(replace(replace(j.property_address, char(10), ' '), char(13), ' '), char(9), ' ') 
    + ' ' + j.property_postcode
    ) as address
  , replace(replace(replace(j.works_to_be_carried_out, char(10), ' '), char(13), ' '), char(9), ' '
    ) as [works ordered]
  , j.job_target_date
  , tmop.F2
from dbo.job j
  inner join dbo.customerproperty cp
    on j.customer_property_id = cp.customer_property_id
  inner join dbo.['tmo properties$'] tmop
    on cp.external_reference = tmop.F1
where dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, j.job_taken_date), 0)
    = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, current_timestamp), 0)
order by received
```

Comment: You need to be a little careful when you hit a year boundary, e.g. these two queries are not equivalent: SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, -1, '20170101')); SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '20170101') - 1;